# Javascript runtime error:function expected ajax call

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, .net

I am doing on ajax call to controller from view in which i am getting an error javascript run time error :function expected.

here my script

```
<script type="text/javascript">

            var jsonData = [];
            var ms1 = $('#ms-tpl').magicSuggest({
                data: jsonData,
                sortOrder: 'name',
                maxResults: false
            });
            $('#Register').click(function () {
                debugger;
                var dataplus = ms1.getValue();
                var tagid = document.getElementById('TagId').value;
                var tagtitle = document.getElementById('TagTitle').value;
                var tagname = document.getElementById('TagContent').value;
                $.ajax()({
                    url: '@Url.Action("Post")' + '?tagid=' + tagid + '?tagtitle=' + tagtitle + '?tagname=' + tagname + '?dataplus=' + dataplus,
                    type: 'POST',
                    cache: false,
                    success: function (html) {
                        $('#bind').html(html);

                    }

                });
            });

            $('#click').click(function () {
                debugger;
                alert(ms1.getValue());

            });

    </script>
```

Note: I am using MAgicSelect query to select multiple values.
pls help me with this.

Answer (score 3):

Try `$.ajax({` instead of `$.ajax()({`.

Consider this:

```
function outerFunction() {
    var innerFunction = function() {
        alert('hi');
    };
    return innerFunction;
}
```

Since `outerFunction` actually returns a function, you could do what you were attempting:

```
outerFunction()();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/NsmB7/

However, you can't do this:

```
$.ajax()();
```

because `$.ajax()` doesn't return a function, it returns a jqXHR object. You just want to execute `$.ajax` and pass your config object as a parameter:

```
$.ajax({...});
```

Comment: Great it works .. simple but i think i need more understanding in scripting thank u jason p

Comment: @user3534449 I added a bit more explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Use just like this:

```
  $.ajax({

                url: '',
                contentType: "application/json;",
                dataType: "json",
                type: "POST",
                data: {  },
                success: function (data) {
                    alert(data);

                },
                error: function () {

                },
            });
```

jQuery.post( url, [data], [callback], [type] )

`url:` (String) The URL of the page to load.

`data (Optional)`: (Map) Key/value pairs that will be sent to the server.

`callback (Optional):` (Function) A function to be executed whenever the data is loaded successfully.

`type (Optional):` (String) Type of data to be returned to callback function: “xml”, “html”, “script”, “json”, “jsonp”, or “text”.